# has_many through children of self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some model, it is self-referential. It contains `somethings`, which can be `child` or `parent`, or both.
Is it possible to do something like this?

```
class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Class', foreign_key: :parent_id
    has_many :children, class_name: 'Class', foreign_key: :parent_id
    has_many :somethings, foreign_key: :something_id
    has_many :somethings, through: :children, foreign_key: :something_id
end
```

What I want to do is call something like `parent.somethings` and get whole list of them.
For now all I get is `stack level too deep` error.
Without last line (`has_many :somethings, through: :children, foreign_key: :something_id`) I can only get `child.somethings` and it works perfectly.

So basically I want to get list of `somethings`, that includes `somethings` of every `child` of particular `parent`.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I need exactly `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, so creating method to collect `somethings`, I think is not possible.

P.P.S. Sorry, if my English is not so good :p

Comment: I'm confused by your specification of `foreign_key` for the `:somethings`. You shouldn't need to specify that, and by convention it should actually be `class_id` to reference the parent.

Comment: Well, let's say, I didn't use default key, so I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I've found answer myself, after about an hour of research on [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).
It's pretty simple, so I've done this:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Class', foreign_key: :parent_id
    has_many :children, class_name: 'Class', foreign_key: :parent_id
    has_many :somethings

    def all_somethings(order)
      Something.joins(some_class: :parent).where("some_class_id = :id OR parents_some_classes.id = :id", {id: self.id}).uniq.order(order)
    end
end
```

And I get exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try splitting it into an instance method that gets all the children's `somethings` like this:

```
class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Class', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Class', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :somethings, foreign_key: :something_id

  def all_somethings
    return unless self.children.empty?
    (self.children + self.children.map(&:all_somethings)).uniq
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply it right, 'cause it seems like recursive method, but for some reason it can't call itself for `ActiveRecord::Association`

Comment: Thanks, I think it works fine, but it returns array, so it won't do. Anyway, thanks for help, I'll try to dig in that direction more.

Comment: BTW it will never return, because []==true.

Comment: Fixed. Just check if it's empty

Answer (score 0):

I am writing an updated answer of Jonathan to avoid multiple call to `:all_somethings` and making query to get all the results. I hope this will also give you the results.

```
class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Class', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Class', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :somethings, foreign_key: :something_id
  has_many :childrens_somethings, through: :children, foreign_key: :something_id,
            class_name: "Something"

  def all_somethings
    return unless self.children.empty?
    (self.children + self.children_somethings).uniq
  end
end
```

Comment: Yea, thanks, I fidured it out on my own a while ago, but used `any?` method it's a tiny bit shorter :)